# How to check available disk space using SAS

Tags: sas

How can I check the space left on a drive and if it is less than 1GB to output a message using SAS.
I only have a code that checks the SAS file size.

Comment: Desktop or server?  And what operating system?

Comment: This depends on your installation. Your question cannot be answered with your given information.

Comment: I would like to check a server's drive space(g:)

Comment: What server, operating system?.  What have you tried thus far?  Got any code?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit, and it is a network drive named G:. The last code on this page is working but is printing the space available of all drives, I would just like to proc print the space available on the G: drive and in gigabytes not bytes.. I have tried few stuff in the proc print but it won't work. thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I've basically modified the code available in [this](https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/get-free-disk-space-sas-windows/) link according to your requirement. I've also added a bit of code to fix issues faced due to quotes and the pipe command. Basically you should let SAS deal with quotes  before passing on the code.

```
%macro windows_bytes_free(sm_path);

%global mv_bytes_free;
%let mv_bytes_free = -1;  /* In case of error */
%let filepath = %sysfunc(quote(%qsysfunc(dequote(&sm_path)))); /* To prevent issues with quotes remove quotes if present and apply it again*/

/* Run the DIR command and retrieve results using an unnamed pipe */
filename tempdir pipe %sysfunc(quote(dir /-c  &filepath  | find "bytes free")) ;

    data _null_;
        infile tempdir length=reclen ;
        input line $varying1024. reclen ;

        re = prxparse('/([0-9]+) bytes/');  /* Parse the output of DIR using a Perl regular expression */

        if prxmatch(re, line) then do;
            bytes_str = prxposn(re, 1, line);
            bytes = input(bytes_str, 20.);
            call symput('mv_bytes_free', bytes);    /* Assign available disk space in bytes to a global macro variable */
            kb = bytes /1024;
            mb = kb / 1024;
            gb = mb / 1024;
            format bytes comma20.0;
            format kb mb gb comma20.1;

            /* Write a note to the SAS log */
            put "NOTE: &sm_path " bytes= kb= mb= gb=;
            if gb<1 then put '** Available space is less than 1 gb';
            else put '** Enough space is available';

        end;

    run;

    %if &mv_bytes_free eq -1 %then %put ERROR: error in windows_bytes_free macro;

%mend;
```

An example of how to use this macro for the C: drive

```
%windows_bytes_free(c:);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it and let you know :)

Comment: ERROR: Expecting comma (to separate macro parameters) or close parenthesis (to end parameter
       list) but found: :
ERROR: A dummy macro will be compiled

Comment: I get the above errors with this code even though I change the path to c:

Comment: 271  %macro windows_bytes_free(\\SERVER\G:);
ERROR: Invalid macro parameter name \.  It should be a valid SAS identifier no longer than 32
       characters.
ERROR: A dummy macro will be compiled

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out but now the code has 2 lines that are modified, the actual `pipe` command and the additional `filename` variable

Answer (score 2):

Tazz:

Presuming you are running SAS on a Windows platform -- Piping `wmic` command output into SAS can deliver vast amounts of information about the system, including the freespace on the disks.

WMIC - Using Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx;

```
%let csvdata = %sysfunc(pathname(work))\wmic_output.csv;

filename wmic_csv "&csvdata" encoding="utf-16";
filename gather pipe "wmic logicaldisk get name,size,freespace /format:csv"; 

* process the wmic command and strip off blank first row and extraneous CR character at end of line;
data _null_;
  infile gather; 
  input;
  if _n_ > 1;
  _infile_ = compress(_infile_, '0d'x);
  file wmic_csv;
  put _infile_;
run;

proc import replace out=diskinfo file=wmic_csv dbms=csv;
run;

data _null_;
  set diskinfo;
  if freespace < 1e9 then put "WARNING: " name "has remaining" freespace=;
run;
```

wmic can also export it's information in XML format -- the output is more complicated but extremely capable.  This sample code uses SAS' `xmlv2` engine and the `automap=` option:

```
* WMIC - Using Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line;
* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx;

%let xmldata = %sysfunc(pathname(work))\wmic_output.xml;
%let xmlautomap  = %sysfunc(pathname(work))\wmic_output-automap.xml;
%let xmlmap =  %sysfunc(pathname(work))\wmic_output-map.xml;

filename wmic "&xmldata" encoding="utf-16";
filename wmicmap "&xmlmap";

filename gather pipe "wmic logicaldisk get name,size,freespace /format:rawxml > ""&xmldata""";

data _null_;
  infile gather;
  input;
  put _infile_;
  rc = sleep(.1,1);
run;

libname wmic xmlv2 automap=replace xmlmap=wmicmap;

proc copy in=wmic out=work;
run;

proc transpose data=work.property out=properties(drop=_name_) suffix=_text;
  by instance_ordinal;
  id property_name;
  var value; 
run;

filename gather;
filename wmic;
filename wmicmap;
```

Comment: The last code seems to work and I get results from all drives available, but I would like one specific drive G: which is a server drive as well..